# Magento2 need to throw 500 internal server error in webapi response

Tags: magento2, error, exception, webapi, response

Can anyone let me know how to throw 500 internal error in api response with REST API? i have used below right now:

```
throw new NoSuchEntityException(
__(
    'Field : '.$fields.' required.'
));
```

but it throws error code 400, i need 500 error code exactly default magento throws error if key is wrong in parameter.

I have used below code:
if (!isset($postData[$fields])) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(
                 __(
                   'Field : '.$fields.' has wrong value.'
                 ), 0, \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
            }

Please find attached screenshot of 400 error:
[image: 400 error]

Answer (score 2):

Try below code, I think it will work for you.

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(
 __(
   'Field : '.$fields.' required.'
 ), 0, \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
```

Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: I have tried but it throws 400 Bad Request

Comment: Ok let me check @bhargavshastri

Comment: It throws 500, Can you please update your question with whole function.

Comment: edited my question, please check

Comment: API's endpoint is magento's default one or you are trying this with custom API?

Comment: yes i am using custom API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83428/discussion-between-ramkishan-and-bhargav-shastri).

Comment: Web API exception should not be used directly by any modules except for Magento_Webapi. During web API requests, all exceptions are converted to this exception,which is then used for proper error response generation.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link it might help:

[Common Error HTTP Codes in Magento Rest API](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/error-http-codes-in-magento-2-rest-api/)

Comment: this link is not opening

Comment: @bhargavshastri i think link is working you should check before down vote  the answer thanks.

Comment: The link is not working